# XPath and PHP, pick specific items from query

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to loop over a HTML doc, specifically a table and pick specific table cells inside each row.

So I'm grabbing the rows "/tr" from the table I want, however, I'm now confused on how I can then when looping over the rows, pick specific "td" table cell contents?

So inside the foreach loop, I want to create headings and stick specific cells under it, does that make sense?

This is the current PHP code, which ends up echo'ing all contents of all td's inside each tr - obviously not what I want.

```
$version_list = new DOMDocument;
$version_list->loadHtml($version_html);

$xpath_r = new DOMXPath($version_list);
$versions = $xpath_r->query("//table[contains(@class, 'devices')]/tr");

foreach ($versions as $version)
{
    echo '<strong>Version</strong><br />';
    echo $version->nodeValue . '<br />';
}
```

Example HTML:

```
<table class="devices">
  <tr>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>Works</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.0</td>
    <td>Broken</td>
</table>
```

So I want to pick cell 1 and cell 2 for each row, inside the foreach loop.

So I want something like:

```
echo '<strong>Version</strong><br />';
echo $version->nodeValue (first cell) . '<br />';
echo '<strong>Status</strong><br />';
echo $version->nodeValue (second cell) . '<br />';
```

Comment: Updated answer, I got ya now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean you only want to grab the version?

If so use: `"//table[contains(@class, 'devices')]/tr/td[1]"`

*If not add your desired output.*

**Update:**

You either need to loop over each child node or run another query again if you want an index of children that you can pluck out:

```
<?php
$version_list = new DOMDocument;
$version_list->loadHtml($version_html);

$xpath_r = new DOMXPath($version_list);
$versions = $xpath_r->query("//table[contains(@class, 'devices')]/tr");

foreach ($versions as $version) {
    $children = $xpath_r->query('*', $version);
    echo '<strong>Version</strong><br />';
    echo $children->item(0)->nodeValue. '<br />';
    echo '<strong>Status</strong><br />';
    echo $children->item(1)->nodeValue. '<br />';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/9WmnW

Or with [getElementsByTagName()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php)

```
<?php
$version_list = new DOMDocument;
$version_list->loadHtml('<table class="devices">
  <tr>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>Works</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2.0</td>
    <td>Broken</td>
</table>');

$xpath_r = new DOMXPath($version_list);
$versions = $xpath_r->query("//table[contains(@class, 'devices')]/tr");

foreach ($versions as $version) {
    $children = $version->getElementsByTagName('td');
    echo '<strong>Version</strong><br />';
    echo $children->item(0)->nodeValue. '<br />';
    echo '<strong>Status</strong><br />';
    echo $children->item(1)->nodeValue. '<br />';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/0FF1n

Comment: It says exactly what I want :) "So I want to pick cell 1 and cell 2 for each row, inside the foreach loop." - Updated to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Your foreach is contradicting as its only showing version. :/

Comment: That is what I have right now, I've updated it again to try and be clearer.